# How to start rserve automatically from java in windows

Tags: java, r, eclipse, rserve

I have created a java application in eclipse. The application used Rserve package to connect to R and run r scripts. Before running my application, i have to start rserve from within Rstudio like this:

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
```

This Java code would be bundled as an executable file, so is there a way that Rserve() is invoked automatically(in windows) as soon as the code is run so that I can skip this manual step of starting Rserve using through RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The https://github.com/yannrichet/rsession project achieves exactly that for you.

Though it might be interesting to have a look at this: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-context-r
As it integrates RSession and keeps a pool of Rserve connections for performance reasons without you having to do much for it. You can also switch to other runtime solutions like JRI, RCaller, Renjin without having to change your script code.

Comment: To use JRI, we have to set path of different DLL dir and jar files. My concern is that if i use my project in a different computer would i have to reset all the paths again? and if i deploy my app, how would the path be set?

Comment: Normally you put the folder of the Rscript executable into the PATH of the application, though when you look at rsession, you will see it additionally tries to read the R installation folder from the registry and also tries some common paths to find the executable. Though it would not be hard improve the library to also allow adding a configurable path to search in, so you can configure it via a startup parameter from your main application (or ideally rather a system property).

Comment: Ah I noticed you asked about JRI (the above comment was abour Rsession), you can also ensure that the lib is found by adding it to the java.library.path alternatively to the system properties I provide (you can override them during startup via the command line argument "-Dproperty.name=value" during application startup if you use the AMain class as provided by the invesdwin-context project), though the problem is always the same with native libraries. That is why I added support for RCaller, Rserve, Renjin as alternatives to JRI

Comment: You can read more about the system properties mechanisms provided by invesdwin-context here: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-context Also you can disable the platform initialization completely to roll your own solution. The R modules also work without having a spring-context initialized

Comment: Thanks you for all the information. I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to do this, but the way I've solved this is by starting it up console style from within my java program. For this to work, you have to put the path to the R executables in your systems path:

```
public Process rserve = null;

public static void startRServer() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    // check the runtime environment to see if there's an active Rserve running
    String existingRserve = "";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq Rserve.exe\"");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        existingRserve = in.readLine();
    } catch(IOException e){}

    if(rserve == null || existingRserve.contains("No tasks are running")) {
        // start and rserve if we don't have one for this run yet, 
        // or if it has unexpectedly failed since we last used it
        try {
            rserve = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript -e \"library(Rserve); Rserve()\"");
            rserve.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("*** R Error: Unable to start the R server ***");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose i give the path to the R executable in my system path. Now if i use my project in a different computer would i have to reset the path? I am asking causing i am hoping to deploy my app and i am confused about this.

Comment: Unfortunately for this method, the path to the R executable folder needs to be placed in the System Environment Variables for every machine this program is run on. I'm not sure if there's a way to do this from within your Java program (my guess would be no, as that would be a massive security hole...but it's possible)